# For which values of $\lambda$ are the following vectors linearly dependent in $R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question in my work book that I think I understand, but I'm somehow struggling to arrive at the answer as it's given in the book. Here it is: For which values of $\lambda$ are the following vectors $(\lambda,-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}), (-\frac{1}{2},\lambda,-\frac{1}{2}), (-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},\lambda)$ linearly dependent in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Well I know that I can use the determinant of the matrix whose columns are given by the above vectors to determine for which values of $\lambda$ the determinant is $0$.

Working out the determinant I get $\lambda^3-\frac{1}{4}\lambda$.

Then $\lambda^3-\frac{1}{4}\lambda = 0$, works out to $\lambda = 0, \lambda = -\frac{1}{2}, \lambda = \frac{1}{2}$

The solution in my work book gives a solution of $\lambda = 1, \lambda = -\frac{1}{2}$.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The determinant is given by $\lambda^3 -\frac{1}{4} - \frac{3 \lambda }{4}$.

Comment: @Hetebrij. Thank you. You've helped me zero in on a mistake I kept making when finding the determinant. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Row-reduction is easy to do here if you change the order of the vectors. You also can remove the denominators, multiplying each vector by $2$:

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&-1&2\lambda\\ -1&2\lambda&-1\\2\lambda&-1&-1
\end{bmatrix}
\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&-1&2\lambda\\ 0&2\lambda+1&-2\lambda-1\\0&-2\lambda-1&4\lambda^2-1
\end{bmatrix}
\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&-1&\lambda\\ 0&2\lambda+1&-2\lambda-1\\0&0&2(2\lambda+1)(\lambda-1)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Thus we see:

- if $\lambda \neq1,-\frac12$, the system of vectors has rank $3$,
- if $\lambda =1$, it has rank $2$,
- if $\lambda =-\frac12$, it has rank $1$.

Comment: Thanks. It's always great to see an alternative approach

Answer (score 2):

A more explicit way to do this would be by considering

\begin{align} v_1 = (\lambda,a,a),\\ v_2 = (a,\lambda,a), \\ v_3 = (a,a,\lambda),\end{align}
such that $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is fixed. (In this case, $a=-1/2$.)

We want to find $\lambda$ such that $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are LD. If these vectors are LD, then $\exists c,d \in\mathbb{R}: cv_1+dv_2=v_3$. That is:

\begin{align}\begin{cases}c\lambda+da=a \\ ca+d\lambda=a \\ (c+d)a=\lambda\end{cases}\implies \begin{cases}(c+d)(a+\lambda) = 2a \\ (c+d)a=\lambda\end{cases}\implies \begin{cases}(c+d+1)\lambda = 2a \\ (c+d)a=\lambda\end{cases}\end{align}

And we can deduce for $a,\lambda\neq 0$:

\begin{align}&(c+d)(c+d+1)\lambda a = 2\lambda a \\ \implies &(c+d)(c+d+1)= 2 \\ \implies &(c+d) = 1 \text{ or } -2.\end{align}

So, from $(c+d)a=\lambda$, we have $\lambda = -2a,\lambda = a$. In the case $a=-1/2$ we have, indeed, $\lambda=1,\lambda=-1/2$.